# Finite global dimension via the Cartan determinant

Tags: co.combinatorics, rt.representation-theory, homological-algebra, computer-algebra

Let $A=T(KQ)$ be the trivial extension algebra of a path algebra of Dynkin type $KQ$.
The indecomposable module of $A$ correspond to the roots of $Q$ (and not just the positive roots as for $KQ$).
Let $M$ be a generatr of mod-$A$, that is $M=A \oplus X$ with $X$ an $A$-module without projective summands.

> Question 1: Is it true that the algebra $B_M:=End_A(M)$ has finite global dimension if and only if $B_M$ has Cartan determinant equal to one?

Note that checking with the computer whether the Cartan determinant is equal to one takes just some seconds, while testing for finite global dimension is basically impossible for large $M$. Thus it would be quite interesting when the question is true although I have no evidence besides knowing that it is true for Dynkin types $A_1$ and $A_2$.

> Question 2: How many generators $M$ are there such that $B_M$ has Cartan determinant equal to one (or finite global dimension)?

The sequence starts for Dynkin type $A_n$ with:

$A_1 : 1$

$A_2 : 13$

$A_3 : 412$